# Display Pop with respect to edited Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Onclick Text, we are displaying Pop Up after the last word in a Text....

[image]

We are using this logic : `left = layer.width + layer.x`

**Code** :

```
document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 9 + 'px'
```

User can edit the text from their side....

**Issue** :

Once user edit text , Pop up is fixed in same place as in [Link1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Gx0iMGghSxVaXu0DHT7mSU8CwbPf8ZK/view)....

**Requirement** :

Pop up should display after the last word of edited text as [Link2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PCIIr7OPwx9Ffb8Z3WzkxSrd9vTuA-cT/view)....

[image]

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

// json file

let jsonData = {
  "layers": [{
    "x": 0,
    "height": 450,
    "layers": [{
      "x": 0,
      "layers": [{
          "x": 57,
          "y": 33,
          "src": "2ccd95bae3f2a0c8249205ca5dfbed24_Montserrat-Bold.ttf",
          "type": "text",
          "size": 67,
          "text": "First Line",
          "name": "edit_good"
        },
        {

          "x": 121,
          "y": 99,
          "src": "180ef82d12e3eee668a3f6b51ea444e9_Font972.otf",
          "type": "text",
          "size": 67,
          "text": "Second line",
          "name": "edit_good_1"
        }
      ],
    }, ],
    "width": 500,
    "name": "L1"
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  // get the text from json - ignore it

  function getAllSrc(layers) {
    let arr = [];
    layers.forEach(layer => {
      if (layer.src) {
        arr.push({
          src: layer.src,
          x: layer.x,
          y: layer.y,
          name: layer.name
        });
      } else if (layer.layers) {
        let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
        if (newArr.length > 0) {
          newArr.forEach(({
            src,
            x,
            y,
            name
          }) => {
            arr.push({
              src,
              x: (layer.x + x),
              y: (layer.y + y),
              name: (name)
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return arr;
  }

  function json(data)

  {
    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;

    let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

    let layer1 = data.layers;
    width = layer1[0].width;
    height = layer1[0].height;
    let counter = 0;
    let table = [];

    for (let {
        src,
        x,
        y,
        name
      } of arr) {
      $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
      if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
        var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
      } else {
        var imageUrl1 = '';
      }
      var mask = $(".container").mask({
        imageUrl: imageUrl1,
        maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
        onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

          img.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": x + "px",
            "top": y + "px"
          });

        },
        id: counter
      });
      table.push(mask);
      fileup.onchange = function() {

        let mask2 = table[target];
        mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
        document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
      };
      counter++;
      // get the text end

    }
    drawText(data);
  }

  json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

  if (layer.type === 'image') return;

  if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
    return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
  }

  if (layer.type === 'text') {
    const url = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + layer.src;

    if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
      fonts.push(url);
      $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
        "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
        "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
        "}");
    }

    // Below is POP UP Code
    const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
    const lightIdString = '#' + lightId

 // Fetch the text and display in page
 
    $('.container').append(

      '<a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="document.getElementById(\'' + lightId + '\').style.display=\'block\';document.querySelector(\'.white_content:not(' + lightIdString + ')\').style.display=\'none\';" ' +
      '<div class="textcontainer" contenteditable="true" ' +
      'style="' +
      'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
      'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
      'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
      '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
      '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
      'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
      'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> content <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById(\'light' + layer.name + '\').style.display=\'none\';">Close</a></div> <div>'
    );

 // pop up left position : 
    document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 9 + 'px'
  }


}
// extempl code end 

// ignore below code

(function($) {
  var JQmasks = [];
  $.fn.mask = function(options) {
    // This is the easiest way to have default options.
    var settings = $.extend({
      // These are the defaults.
      maskImageUrl: undefined,
      imageUrl: undefined,
      scale: 1,
      id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
      x: 0, // image start position
      y: 0, // image start position
      onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
    }, options);


    var container = $(this);

    let prevX = 0,
      prevY = 0,
      draggable = false,
      img,
      canvas,
      context,
      image,
      timeout,
      initImage = false,
      startX = settings.x,
      startY = settings.y,
      div;


    container.updateStyle = function() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        context.beginPath();
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";        
        image.onload = function() {
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
          div.css({
            "width": image.width,
            "height": image.height
          });
          resolve();
        };
      });
    };
  };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
  background: gold;
  position: relative;
}

.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}

.masked-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.textcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF
}

.textcontainer:hover {
  background: red;
  padding: 1px;
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Pen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/wZjqyv

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/na7w83dc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do, simply add timeInterval on your code, so it check always when you change text

Remove this code

```
document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 9 + 'px'
```

and add this code

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 9 + 'px'
}, 100);
```

your problem solved, now your box respectively follow your code

Comment: Perhaps trigger a custom event instead on various events (keydown, clicks etc.)