# Partial Pop up display if we use overflow : hidden

Tags: javascript, css, html

We are Displaying **text** inside **container** as below :

[image]

Onclick Text, We are doing below things :

1.Allowing user to **add more text**

2.Display **Pop Up** Box

[image]

**Issue** :

When User added more text, it was displaying beyond the container, but we wanted to hide the text which displayed beyond the container....

so we added `overflow: hidden;` for the container, but now only **partial** pop up box is displaying as below....

[image]

```js
//  Close text pop up onclick outside

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $('.white_content, .font-select');

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
        $('.font-select').css('display', 'none');
    }
});

// end

var className;

// Display pop up next to text

function closePopUp(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    $('.font-select').css('display', 'none');
    openID = null
}

function openPopUp(el) {
    // console.log(el);
    if (openID != null) {
        closePopUp(openID)
    }

    $('.font-select:first').css({
        display: 'block'
    });

    el.style.display = 'block';
    openID = el;
}



let openID = null;

var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {   
    
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 300,
        "layers": [                      
            {
                "justification": "center",
                "font": "Coustard-Black",
                "x": 190,
                "y": 150,
                "src": "0a7fb3015bb19745da114bc581e96947_Font248.ttf",
                "width": 72,
                "type": "text",
                "color": "red",
                "size": 32,
                "text": "DATE",
                "height": 17,
                "name": "edit_date"
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 350,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "fb_post_4"
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');

$(function() {   

    // IGNORE BELOW CODE

    //  Fetch text from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
                   
            var imageUrl1 = '';                         
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end
                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";               
            };
            counter++;
        }

        // Text
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// IGNORE ABOVE CODE

//Fetch text

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'https://i.imgur.com/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is POP UP Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<input id="font" style="display:none"><a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +          
            '<a class = "close" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close this pop up box</a></div> <div>'
        );    
  
  setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px';
         }, 100);
 }

}
// text end

// IGNORE BELOW CODE 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        
        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };        
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 color: #FFF;
 white-space: pre;
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 position: absolute;
 background: red;
 white-space: pre;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.white_content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 21%;
 height: 40%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background : green">
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div id="container"class="container">
</div>
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/wZYjbE

Comment: There is lot of code, it's always better to just incldue essentials in this just just simple css would do. So what you need is to write your function where popup is inserted outside of modal. Insert it to body and position accordingly.

Comment: why not use a `wrapper` and wrap the input tag in that and then provide it a `max-width` and `overflow: hidden` to that instead

Comment: @JoykalInfotech sorry, i did't knew about wrapper....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer with drag function:

```js
//  Close text pop up onclick outside

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $('.white_content, .font-select');

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
        $('.font-select').css('display', 'none');
    }
});

// end

var className;

// Display pop up next to text

function closePopUp(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
    $('.font-select').css('display', 'none');
    openID = null
}

function openPopUp(el) {
    // console.log(el);
    if (openID != null) {
        closePopUp(openID)
    }

    $('.font-select:first').css({
        display: 'block'
    });

    el.style.display = 'block';
    openID = el;
}



let openID = null;

var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {   
    
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 300,
        "layers": [                      
            {
                "justification": "center",
                "font": "Coustard-Black",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "src": "0a7fb3015bb19745da114bc581e96947_Font248.ttf",
                "width": 72,
                "type": "text",
                "color": "red",
                "size": 32,
                "text": "DATE",
                "height": 17,
                "name": "edit_date"
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 350,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "fb_post_4"
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');

$(function() {   

    // IGNORE BELOW CODE

    //  Fetch text from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
                   
            var imageUrl1 = '';                         
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end
                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";               
            };
            counter++;
        }

        // Text
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// IGNORE ABOVE CODE

//Fetch text

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'https://i.imgur.com/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is POP UP Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('#container').append(
            '<input id="font" style="display:none"><a id ="' + layer.name + '" onclick="openPopUp(' + lightId + ')"' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' 
        );   
      $(".control-container").append('<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +          
            '<a class = "close" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closePopUp(' + lightId + ')">Close this pop up box</a></div> <div>');
  
  setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById(lightId).style.left = layer.x + document.getElementById(layer.name).offsetWidth + 'px';
         }, 100);
 }

}
// text end

// IGNORE BELOW CODE 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        
        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };        
    };
}(jQuery));

$( function() {
    $(".txtContainer").draggable();
  $(".control-container").draggable();
  } );
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 color: #FFF;
  overflow-wrap: initial;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: start;
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 position: absolute;
 background: red;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.white_content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 25%;
 left: 360px!important;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}

.control-container{
  width:100px;
  top:-300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body style="background : green">
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >
  <h5>NOTE : drag the elements to place you want.</h5>
<div id="container"class="container"></div>
<div class="control-container"></div>
```

```
https://codepen.io/ContexDev/pen/ROeBeP
```

Comment: Thanks, once user add more text, You are displaying text in 2nd line, but i want to display only in one line.... text should be hidden beyond the container.....

Comment: I have updated the code, try it now. One thing remaining : i have no idea how to set the cursor at the left side of the input area while typing.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but sorry.... if we add more text, then original text `Date` will not display.....

Comment: can you please check video here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/10LFDyK8K7MnuPRq_jMCHfs4YmY-ZSdRf/view

Comment: But in that website you can drag elements, if you did this your problem is solved! because i will be able to show what i want from the text no matter how long is it. [ see this : https://jqueryui.com/draggable/ ]

Comment: some users may don't know about drag.... If we don't drag also, text will not display beyond container & pop up will display properly in that website , can you please help me to make similar like that website....

Comment: I have updated the code and add drag function, try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192317/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-ahmed-tag-amer).

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply `max-width` in `.txtContainer`, and remove `position: relative;` from container class.

By removing `position` attribute the `div` will come in front and by adding `max-width` the anchor tag will not increase.

Just update above CSS classes:

```
.txtContainer {
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    white-space: pre;
    max-width: 50px;
}

.container {
    background: silver;
    /* position: relative; */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now pop up is `not displaying` after the last word in text..... before it was displaying after the completion of full text..... before i solved issue using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760869/display-pop-with-respect-to-edited-text)

Comment: please check now text will not overlap

Comment: .font-select {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 210px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *: ;
    display: inline;
}       make position absolute

Comment: sorrry, still it didt worked for me : https://imgur.com/RXOMo40 , i appreciate your help , Thanks a lot for your support.....